# What could be causing this error on console even if I am not in playmode?

Tags: unity-game-engine

> TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_THREAD has unfreed allocations

This error keeps appearing in my console after few seconds, even if I clear the console. My scene playmode and pause mode are off, still. What could be causing this ?

Comment: yesterday I got this error. I am using Unity 2017.1.1f1. Did you solved this?

Comment: Is it causing any problems?

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange bug that apparently doesn't have an official solution. Reports begun with **Unity 2017** and it still happens on **Unity 2020 LTS** and **Unity 2021 (beta)**.

Even that they say on their [issue forum](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/assertion-failed-tls-allocator-alloc-temp-thread-dot-dot-dot-error-is-shown-after-building-the-project-for-ios) that was fixed, it wasn't.

#### Workarounds:

##### 1. Reopen project:

Close Unity or close the project. Reopen it with **Unity Hub** or **File > Open** Project as you like.

(May work just for a while)

##### 2. Cleaning cache:

Some users reported that cleaning the cache at **Edit > Preferences > GI Cache > Clean Cache** may solve.

##### 3. Re-import all assets

###### Recommended for small or recently created projects only!!

Go to **Assets > Re-import All**.

That one fixed it for me, but I can't confirm if it applies for all cases.

In my particular case **I suppose** that since I have three Unity versions installed on the Unity Hub some assets were loaded with mismatch versions when creating the project, so I had to reload them from the cloud with the correct versions.

The problem is, for a recently created project, it's not a big deal, but just like the pop-up message for this action on Unity says, it can take **many hours** to re-import all assets depending on the size of the project.